# I get error : ORA-02149 when I use partition table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new in oracle ,I get error :ORA-02149 when I write my code, then I write my code with dynamic sql . please take a look my code .At now is it correct ?
my code which I write is :

```
DECLARE
INPAR_DATE    VARCHAR2(30):=20211005 ;
maxlevel NUMBER;
var_partition VARCHAR2(100);
var_partition_name VARCHAR2(100);
var_execute_query varchar2(500);
BEGIN
  ----------------------------max_level
  SELECT MAX(DEPTH) INTO maxlevel FROM PRAGG.tbl_ledger;
  
  SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(inpar_date,'yyyymmdd'),'j') INTO var_partition FROM dual;
  SELECT 'P'||var_partition INTO var_partition_name FROM dual;

  -----------------------------------tajmiiii   
---    FOR i IN reverse 0..maxlevel-1
--      LOOP

select
  ' INSERT /*+ parallel(auto) */
        INTO pragg.tbl_ledger_branch
          (
            LEDGER_CODE,
            NAME,
            DEPTH,
            PARENT_CODE,
            CUR_BALANCE,
            BALANCE,
            REF_CUR_ID,
            EFF_DATE,
            REF_BRANCH,
            number_date
          )
          (SELECT /*+  parallel(auto) */ 
              b.ledger_code,
              MAX(b.name) ,
              i,
              max(b.PARENT_CODE),
              SUM(a.CUR_BALANCE),
              SUM(a.BALANCE),
              a.REF_CUR_ID,
              max(TO_DATE(inpar_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')),
              a.REF_BRANCH,
              var_partition
            FROM  pragg.tbl_ledger_branch partition('||var_partition_name||') a,
              PRAGG.tbl_ledger b
            WHERE b.DEPTH = i
            AND a.PARENT_CODE = b.ledger_code
            GROUP BY a.REF_CUR_ID,
              a.REF_BRANCH ,
              b.ledger_code
          )x;'
        INTO
            var_execute_query
        FROM
            dual;
 
        COMMIT;
--      END LOOP;
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN'
        || var_execute_query
        || ' END;';
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var_execute_query);  
    COMMIT;
END ;
```

please take a look my code .in your opinion is it ok ?whats the best idea with using this dynamic sql for this solving for write this code with dynamic sql ?

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the entire error message, not just the "ORA-02149" part.  Cut & paste it directly, rather than retyping it.

Comment: Hi , form the error message it ORA-02149 looks like the partition that you are trying to use dose not exists or the Role that you are using to rnu the SQL block dose not have access to the partiton.

Comment: It's not a good idea to hardcode a partitioning naming convention into your program like this. DBAs could change the partitioning, or implement interval partitioning with system names, and that would break your code. You're much better off actually working with the partition key. Plus you can then get rid of all this dynamic SQL and everything would be much simpler.

Comment: What do you try to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code.

- Don't use (hard coded) partition names. If you really need to specify the partition - which I doubt - then you can also specify the partition by value, e.g `pragg.tbl_ledger_branch PARTITION FOR (DATE '2023-03-20')`
- **NEVER** use `TO_DATE(...)` on a value which is already a `DATE`
- An `INSERT` statement does not return anything. Thus your SQL statement does not make much sense.
- A dynamic SQL string must not terminate with a semicolon `;`. Actually your code should not work at all.